# Timer Not Working AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, timer, countdown

I am using a countdown timer.
what the game should do:
my first scene is the countdown and once the countdown reaches 0, it goes to the second scene

the problem is that the countdown will not show up but it will go to the first scene after 15 seconds which is what the countdown is counting down to. However when i renswe only the first scene using ctrl+alt+enter, the countdown shows up. I think the problem is some other code which is interfering.

There is a lot of coding and possible sources of error thereofore I have uploaded my game to the internet. Please do not use! This is the work of Pranavan Kantharajah for a school assignment!

Download to my flash game (AS3):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/039lkek494k65m8/EndOfPart1%20copy.fla

Comment: You need to isolate the problem to something small and demonstrable and then post the code. You can't expect people here to download your game and work through the various possible sources of error. That's not the purpose of this site.

Comment: i am sorry. but i am not very good with flash and this is for a school assignment and our teacher didnt teach us a thing therefore i havent got that much knowledge. There are no errors that show up as well...

Answer (score 0):

just add and complete event to your timer and then try to reset your timer there just like this:

```
var TM:Timer = new Timer(1000,15);
TM.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, do_my_job);
function do_my_job(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    //
}
TM.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, do_this_at_the_end);
function do_this_at_the_end(e:TimerEvent):void
{
   TM.reset();
}
TM.start();
```